# Python - Find date from string

Tags: python

Would anyone know a regex string or another method of obtaining the date and time from this string into variables? The position of the string could change, so line and char no would not work. This is a bit beyond my ability, can it be done?

Thanks

```
Dear Customer,

(Call Transferred) Start Time & Date: 00:05 Monday 6th February 2017               
Completion Time & Date: 06:00 Monday 6th February 2017                 

Details of Work:
```

Comment: use the `DateTime`

Comment: you suggest using regex - what have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works with the example report you've provided. It returns both the start and completion date and should handle day-of-month suffixes like 'th', 'rd', etc.

```
import re

import dateutil.parser

REPORT = \
"""Dear Customer,

(Call Transferred) Start Time & Date: 00:05 Monday 6th February 2017
Completion Time & Date: 06:00 Monday 6th February 2017

Details of Work:"""


def parse_report(data):
    dates = []

    for pattern in ['(?<=Start Time & Date: ).*', '(?<=Completion Time & Date: ).*']:
        date = dateutil.parser.parse(re.search(pattern, data).group(0))
        dates.append(date)

    return dates


if __name__ == '__main__':
    start, completion = parse_report(REPORT)
    print('Started: {}, Completed: {}'.format(start, completion))
```

**Output**

```
Started: 2017-02-06 00:05:00, Completed: 2017-02-06 06:00:00
```

**Edit**

Updated to use `dateutil.parser` instead which simplifies the code (thanks to asongtoruin for the suggestion).

Comment: you could use `dateutil.parser.parse()` rather than `datetime.strptime()` to remove the need to `filter_day_of_month_suffix()`?

Comment: @asongtoruin Thanks, wasn't aware of that package.