# How to Extract Date From String Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have a String Like

> **"Originally Posted on 09 May, 2016. By query 3 j...."**

how can i extract date using python??

I tried this code:

```
dStr = "Originally Posted on 09 May, 2016. By query 3 j...."
date_st = re.findall("(\d+\ \w+,)", dStr)
```

printing date_st, i've got:

**['09 May,']**

what should i do for year??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python - Find date from string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41871635/python-find-date-from-string)

Comment: i tried nearly all solution, i found on stackoverflow. but nothing works.

Comment: Nearly all? try the others? You could post the code you already have?

Comment: @Luke.py i have removed, because i didn't find them useful

Comment: If you post what you tried and show the results, thats a starting point. Currently you are just asking for a code writing service.

Comment: please add code to your answer so we can at least start to help you, you would be lucky to get an answer from a reputable SO member from a question like this

Comment: @Luke.py, please check the code now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there. Just add 4 digits for the year after the `,`. It is better to use `[a-z]+` instead of `\w+` to match the month names as `\w` matches `_` and `0-9` (along with alphabets) as well.

```
re.findall(r'\d+\s[a-z]+,\s\d{4}',s,re.I)
```

Comment: Works Perfect. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You forget to add the year after ',', Only need to add '\d+.' is well.

```
re.findall("(\d+\ \w+, \d+\.)", dStr)
```

You will got this:

```
'09 May, 2016.'
```